# UIDatePicker on iOS 15 stops showing era when Japanese calendar is used

Tags: xcode, uidatepicker, xcode13

My UIDatePicker uses either Gregorian calendar or another calendar of user's choice. When they choose Japanese calendar, the picker shows years with era like this: "平成30年" or "令和2年”.

This was working fine until iOS 14. Now on iOS 15, it's just "30" or "2". Is this a bug, or is there a way to fix it so the era will be shown before year?

I use the following code to reload UIDatePicker on my app.

```
func reloadPickers() -> Void { 
    
    var title = timeZone?.localizedName(for: .standard, locale: locale)
    if (timeZone?.isDaylightSavingTime(for: dateTimeComplete!))! {
        title = timeZone?.localizedName(for: .daylightSaving, locale: locale)
    } else {
    }
    buttonTimeZone.setTitle(title, for: .normal)

    let originalDateSecondsOnly = NSCalendar.current.dateComponents([.second], from: dateTimeComplete!)

    secondPickerView.reloadAllComponents()
    if arraySeconds?.count != 0 {
        secondPickerView.selectRow(second, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
    }
    
    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.era, .year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: dateTimeComplete!)
    let dateWithoutSecond = calendar.date(from: components)

    datePicker.date     = dateWithoutSecond!
    datePicker.timeZone = timeZone!
    datePicker.calendar = calendar
    datePicker.locale   = locale
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(DateChooserViewController.dateUpdated), for: .valueChanged)
    
    timePicker.date     = dateWithoutSecond!
    timePicker.timeZone = timeZone!
    timePicker.calendar = calendar
    timePicker.locale   = locale
    timePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(DateChooserViewController.timeUpdated), for: .valueChanged)
    
}


@IBAction func switchCalendarButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) { //ver2.0.4
    
    print("switchCalendarButtonTapped")
    
    if let alternateCalendar = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "alternateCalendar") as? String {
        
        if useAlternateCalendar {
            useAlternateCalendar = false
            calendar = Calendar.current
            reloadPickers()
        } else {
            switch alternateCalendar {
            case "buddhist":
                calendar = Calendar.init(identifier: .buddhist)
            case "chinese":
                calendar = Calendar.init(identifier: .chinese)
            case "coptic":
                calendar = Calendar.init(identifier: .coptic)
            case "ethiopicAmeteAlem":
                calendar = Calendar.init(identifier: .ethiopicAmeteAlem)
            case "ethiopicAmeteMihret":
                calendar = Calendar.init(identifier: .ethiopicAmeteMihret)
            case "gregorian":
                calendar = Calendar.init(identifier: .gregorian)
            case "hebrew":
                calendar = Calendar.init(identifier: .hebrew)
            case "indian":
                calendar = Calendar.init(identifier: .indian)
            case "islamic":
                calendar = Calendar.init(identifier: .islamic)
            case "islamicCivil":
                calendar = Calendar.init(identifier: .islamicCivil)
            case "islamicTabular":
                calendar = Calendar.init(identifier: .islamicTabular)
            case "islamicUmmAlQura":
                calendar = Calendar.init(identifier: .islamicUmmAlQura)
            case "japanese":
                calendar = Calendar.init(identifier: .japanese)
            case "persian":
                calendar = Calendar.init(identifier: .persian)
            case "republicOfChina":
                calendar = Calendar.init(identifier: .republicOfChina)
            default:
                print("do nothing")
            }
            useAlternateCalendar = true
            reloadPickers()
            
            if !(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).canUseTimeCalculation() { //ver2.0.6
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("Please Upgrade", comment: ""), message: NSLocalizedString("Please upgrade to enable this function.", comment: ""), preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Upgrade", comment: ""), 
                                              style: .default,
                                              handler: {
                                                (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
                                                print("Upgrade is pressed")
                                                self.useAlternateCalendar = false
                                                self.calendar = Calendar.current
                                                self.reloadPickers()
                                                self.openInAppPurchaseForTimeCalcVC(forFree: false)
                }))
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Cancel", comment: ""),
                                              style: .cancel,
                                              handler: {
                                                (alert: UIAlertAction!) in
                                                print("Cancel is pressed")
                                                self.useAlternateCalendar = false
                                                self.calendar = Calendar.current
                                                self.reloadPickers()
                }))
                self.show(alert, sender: self)
            } else {
                (presentingViewController as! ViewController).shouldCountNumberOfTimeCalcTrial = true
            }
        }

    } else {
        
        if Locale.current.regionCode == "JP" {
            if Calendar.current.identifier == .gregorian {
                UserDefaults.standard.setValue("japanese", forKey: "alternateCalendar")
            } else {
                UserDefaults.standard.setValue("gregorian", forKey: "alternateCalendar")
            }
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
            switchCalendarButtonTapped(self)
        } else {
            changeAlternateCalendar()
        }
    }
            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using the Chinese calendar with UIDatePicker, but I found that a UIDatePicker for setting the birthday of a contact in the "Phone" app for iOS 15 was displayed normally.

I found that the `locale` property of this UIDatePicker is set like this:

```swift
Locale(identifier: "zh_CN@calendar=chinese")
```

So I presume you should set it to:

```swift
let identifier = Locale.autoupdatingCurrent.identifier + "@calendar=chinese"
datePicker.locale = Locale(identifier: identifier)
```

Displayed on my iOS 15 device with "平成30年" and "令和2年".

Comment: To be generic, I ended up using like: let identifier = Locale.autoupdatingCurrent.identifier + "@calendar=\(calendar.identifier)", but you're spot on. Very helpful!